# Codeigniter tracking users without cookies

Tags: codeigniter

Working on a project in codeigniter.

I've got clients sending requests from an app (I have no control over) to a router app (I have no control over).  The router gives me a unique identifier for each person talking to my app (in a post variable).  How would you suggest tracking sessions for users without using a cookies between requests.  I would use the CI sessions to track but it tracks off of IP address, and most of the requests from the router app to mine will have the same IP address.

Comment: Just FYI... even using `ci_sessions` in a DB will use a cookie

Answer (score 1):

You can try storing session to database or use apache/IIS log. Many free web apps are available to read these logs. I've used awstats for reading IIS log for getting traffic info.

Answer (score 0):

You could go the old-fashioned route and put the tracking data into the URL. Append the unique ID from the routing app to every link on the page in the form of a GET parameter. Read that in on subsequent pages and regurgitate it on all subsequent URLs.

Certainly  not sexy, but in the world of dealing with applications you can't control (aka the "real" world) it might not be the worth option.